# How do I use enums without specifying the enum class each time?

Tags: java, enums

I'm looking for a faster way to use enums as parameters. like if I have a method

`void junk(EnumVar var){`

Instead of typing `EnumVar.VAR_1` I'd rather just type "VAR1" and then use content assist to do the rest, or have VAR_1 be acceptable alone, or even just use content assist give me some options. I know eclipse will do this when I type `enumvar.`...

Is there any way to have eclipse help me work with enums faster? sort of how it does with switches.

Comment: The tag does apply, I'm talking about content assist Paul -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) may be what you need.

For instance try `import static foo.bar.MyEnum.VAR_1;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, include a static import with the rest of your imports, like this:

```
import static my.package.EnumVar.*;
```